# Non-parametric Levene's test by Nordstokke and Zumbo

Tags: anova, nonparametric, heteroscedasticity, unbalanced-classes, levenes-test

The example they mention is using a one-way ANOVA. What if I have two factors (3x11) and a dependent variable, can I do a two-way ANOVA to calculate the univariate levene's test? If so, how would I report it --assuming I would have the test of between-subjects effects of the two factors and the interaction. In my case, they all turn out to be significant at the .000 level.

Source: Nordstokke, D. W., & Zumbo, B. D. (2010). A new nonparametric Levene Test for Equal Variances, Psicologica, 31, 401-430

Something close to what I am looking for is explained in a video called: "Levene's test - SPSS (part 3)" [Youtube link](http://youtu.be/_w5FM_1WL-M)

Comment: You should definitely post a link to the video.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the Youtube link.